# Google Translate API authentication error

Tags: google-translate

I am trying to call the Google Translate API and using the following to authenticate from my local - gcloud auth application-default login.

The command works successfully and I am authenticated but when I try to call the API i get the following error message which indicates that it is being read as an anonymous API call

google.cloud.exceptions.Forbidden: 403 Daily Limit Exceeded

Comment: Looks you're hitting the quota instead of getting auth error

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue too this week,

I thought i was well authenticated but when i was running my code which is C# using the google translate API v2 package, it gave me the same 403 code daily limit exceeded,
I fiddled around with the CLI, made several accounts, service accounts API keys and all and it never worked.

https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/getting-started/hello-world

this page, (the .NET guide part) says you should be using the google cloud platform plugin they release for visual studio, and login via that, i used it and it worked.

If you look on the bottom left part there are guides for any other language that you might be using. (consider adding that as info it helps me help you).

I would love it if it only worked via CLI but as long as it works i guess it's fine...